# Mongoose NodeJS - getting properties of a query with .select subquery

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have GET request body in the routes.js file inside of my NodeJS|Express application.

```
await Furniture.findOne({ name: givenName }, async (err, result) => {
    // make it pure object
    var pureObject = result.toObject();
    // return result
    res.json({
      pt: pureObject.pt,
      en: pureObject.en,
      pl: pureObject.pl
    });
  }).select("names -_id");
```

When I try to print, i.e: [`console.log(pureObject.pt)`], they are undefined.

1. When I print a WHOLE OBJECT [`console.log(pureObject)`], I get exactly what I want:

   { names: { pt: 'name in pt', en: 'name in en', pl: 'name in pl' }
2. Also: when I remove 'select' subquery, I can get those specific properties without a problem.

Why is that? I tried pureObject['pt'] , but obviously it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `console.log(pureObject)` gives the following output:

```js
{ names: { pt: 'name in pt', en: 'name in en', pl: 'name in pl' }
```

So, you need to use `pureObject.names.pt`, i.e., `console.log(pureObject.names.pt)`.

**Why?** It's clear from the output that `pureObject` has an object `names` which has `pt`, `en`, and `pl`.

Comment: Thank You! no comment for my mistake... Topic to be closed.